# Google Sheets Reference form Index function

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have reference based index function in an xlsx spreadsheet

```
=SUM(B10:INDEX(B10:AJ10,$D$5-1))
```

However importing this spreadsheet in google sheets broke the function as Index doesn't return reference any more instead return the value at the index.

I wonder how can I solve this problem in google sheets.

Answer (score 2):

That formula doesn't look correct. You are using the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) for the extents of the range in a single row but you are returning the row number, not the column number to extend to.

```
=SUM(B10:INDEX(B10:AJ10, , $D$5-1))
```

That small modification should correct the range. With 7 in D5 this would be `SUM(B10:G10)` in Excel.

However, Google-Docs cannot use INDEX like that. Use the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) instead.

```
=SUM(offset(B10:AJ10, 0, 0, 1, $D$5-1))
```